# Why is this closure not working as I expect it to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have the following html and javascript (jQuery):

```
<div class="container-a">
    <div class="element">...</div>
    <div class="element">...</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container-b">
    <div class="element">...</div>
    <div class="element">...</div>
    ...
</div>

<script>
    function cycle($container) {
        setInterval(function() {
            $active = $container.find(':last-child')
            $next = $active.prev();
            $next.css({opacity:0});
            $next.insertAfter($active);
            $next.animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function() {
                $active.insertBefore($container.find(':first-child'));
            });
        }, 3500);
    }

    $(function() {
         cycle($('.container-a'));
         cycle($('.container-b'));
    })
</script>
```

When I run cycle(..) on just one or the other of .container-a or .container-b things work fine (the elements are faded in one after the next by moving the last element to the beginning of the container after an opacity transition).  However, when I run cycle on both as above, then the elements in container-a don't transition properly.

I know that it is because of a closure issue because when I step through the code there are cases when the animation complete function is run and $container is .container-a but $active.parent() and $next.parent() are .container-b.  I'm having trouble figuring out why exactly this is the case and how to fix it.

Comment: You should use "var" before your variables declaration inside your closure so it keeps them private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't use `var` for any of your variable declarations, so they're all implicit globals. You're not using the variable-scoping behavior of closures, because none of your functions have local variables.

Instead, you must use `var`:

```
var $active = $container.find(':last-child')
var $next = $active.prev();
```

Strict mode does not allow implicit globals. If you add `"use strict";` to the top of your `setInterval` callback (or the top of your whole file), you'll see an error that `$active` is not defined.

See also [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/710446)

Answer (score 1):

$next is a global variable. Add "var" to the beginning of this line:

```
$next = $active.prev();
```